# Javascript update causing grief

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not a javascript developer by any means what so ever, however am stuck behind a JS problem.

If somebody could help me figure out what the problem may be would be amazing.

The bit of script that is falling over is:

```
        $('button').each(function()
            {
            var curr_title = $(this).attr('title');

            if(curr_title.length > 0)   $(this).button({ icons: { primary: curr_title } });
            else                        $(this).button();
            });
```

The error is

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

This works no problems at all in previous releases of the code. however the only change is updated Jquery.

Does anyone know if this is likely to be the problem?

Again. Apologies if im being stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).attr('title');` is undefined, so has no length. does your button contain a title, if your testing for wether the attibute exists try:

```
$('button').each(function()
            {
            var curr_title = $(this).attr('title');

            if(curr_title != undefined)  
                $(this).button({ icons: { primary: curr_title } });
            else                        
                $(this).button();
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

The value returned in this line is `undefined` (probably because the button it refers to has no such attribute specified.)

```
var curr_title = $(this).attr('title');
```

jQuery changed the behavior of [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) in version 1.6

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set.

So the call in the `if` statement fails. To "repair" this, you could just add a check for `undefined` like this:

```
if( (typeof curr_title != 'undefined') && (curr_title.length > 0)) {
   $(this).button({ icons: { primary: curr_title } });
} else {
   $(this).button();
}
```

Comment: undefined shouldn't be a string. It's an object.

Comment: @liam Where did i specify `undefined` as a string? If you mean the `typeof ...` statement, have a look at the spec, as [`typeof` always returns a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)!

Comment: fair enough, don't see what advantage typeof brings to this as a separate note but there you go

Comment: @Liam; Sirko is comparing the type of the curr_title object to the string 'undefined' 
hence: typeof curr_title OR typeof(curr_title)

Answer (score 0):

looks like you might have a button in the markup without a "title" attribute.  For this button (or buttons) `curr_title` is undefined, so calling .length on it raises the exception

Comment: so use undefined's answer to defend against this error and check your markup